# React Native 0.71 fail to build on iOS with custom build config (React-Codegen, FBReactNativeSpec)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I get stuck since 2 days on the following problem:

For the needs of my ReactNative App I need to have 3 differents xcode build config.

When I compile my App with de default build config (Debug) it works, but when I create a new build config (by using "Duplicate Debug Configuration" in XCode editor) it fails with the following error:

```
Node found at: /usr/local/bin/node
[Codegen] Processing react-native core libraries
[Codegen] Found react-native


[Codegen] >>>>> Searching for codegen-enabled libraries in /Users/gtaja/Projects/altitude/FormulaireQPZ/node_modules
[Codegen] Found react-native-gesture-handler
[Codegen] Found react-native-image-picker
[Codegen] Found react-native-safe-area-context
[Codegen] Found react-native-screens
[Codegen] Found react-native-svg


[Codegen] >>>>> Searching for codegen-enabled libraries in react-native.config.js


[Codegen] >>>>> Searching for codegen-enabled libraries in the app


[Codegen] >>>>> Processing FBReactNativeSpec
[Codegen] Generated schema: /var/folders/7_/xtsxclg94s99lhpg5q1f2ypc0000gn/T/FBReactNativeSpecRNCjPV/schema.json
cp: Altitude-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/DerivedSources/generated/source/codegen/out/build/generated/ios is not a directory
Error: Command failed: cp -R /var/folders/7_/xtsxclg94s99lhpg5q1f2ypc0000gn/T/FBReactNativeSpecRNCjPV/out/* /Users/gtaja/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FormulaireQPZ-bptcjaoriwufhefhkhiwjqszhpur/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug Altitude-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/DerivedSources/generated/source/codegen/out/build/generated/ios
cp: Altitude-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/DerivedSources/generated/source/codegen/out/build/generated/ios is not a directory

    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:861:11)
    at execSync (node:child_process:932:15)
    at generateCode (/Users/gtaja/Projects/altitude/FormulaireQPZ/node_modules/react-native/scripts/codegen/generate-artifacts-executor.js:349:3)
    at /Users/gtaja/Projects/altitude/FormulaireQPZ/node_modules/react-native/scripts/codegen/generate-artifacts-executor.js:374:5
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at generateNativeCodegenFiles (/Users/gtaja/Projects/altitude/FormulaireQPZ/node_modules/react-native/scripts/codegen/generate-artifacts-executor.js:362:13)
    at Object.execute (/Users/gtaja/Projects/altitude/FormulaireQPZ/node_modules/react-native/scripts/codegen/generate-artifacts-executor.js:532:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gtaja/Projects/altitude/FormulaireQPZ/node_modules/react-native/scripts/generate-codegen-artifacts.js:64:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14) {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [
    null,
    <Buffer >,
    <Buffer 63 70 3a 20 41 6c 74 69 74 75 64 65 2d 69 70 68 6f 6e 65 73 69 6d 75 6c 61 74 6f 72 2f 52 65 61 63 74 2d 43 6f 64 65 67 65 6e 2e 62 75 69 6c 64 2f 44 ... 82 more bytes>
  ],
  pid: 89223,
  stdout: <Buffer >,
  stderr: <Buffer 63 70 3a 20 41 6c 74 69 74 75 64 65 2d 69 70 68 6f 6e 65 73 69 6d 75 6c 61 74 6f 72 2f 52 65 61 63 74 2d 43 6f 64 65 67 65 6e 2e 62 75 69 6c 64 2f 44 ... 82 more bytes>
}


[Codegen] Done.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Node found at: /usr/local/bin/node

[Codegen] Processing react-native core libraries

[Codegen] Found react-native





[Codegen] >>>>> Searching for codegen-enabled libraries in /Users/gtaja/Projects/altitude/FormulaireQPZ/node_modules

[Codegen] Found react-native-gesture-handler

[Codegen] Found react-native-image-picker

[Codegen] Found react-native-safe-area-context

[Codegen] Found react-native-screens

[Codegen] Found react-native-svg





[Codegen] >>>>> Searching for codegen-enabled libraries in react-native.config.js





[Codegen] >>>>> Searching for codegen-enabled libraries in the app





[Codegen] >>>>> Processing FBReactNativeSpec

[Codegen] Generated schema: /var/folders/7_/xtsxclg94s99lhpg5q1f2ypc0000gn/T/FBReactNativeSpecRNCjPV/schema.json

cp: Altitude-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/DerivedSources/generated/source/codegen/out/build/generated/ios is not a directory

Error: Command failed: cp -R /var/folders/7_/xtsxclg94s99lhpg5q1f2ypc0000gn/T/FBReactNativeSpecRNCjPV/out/* /Users/gtaja/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FormulaireQPZ-bptcjaoriwufhefhkhiwjqszhpur/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug Altitude-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/DerivedSources/generated/source/codegen/out/build/generated/ios

cp: Altitude-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/DerivedSources/generated/source/codegen/out/build/generated/ios is not a directory



    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:861:11)

    at execSync (node:child_process:932:15)

    at generateCode (/Users/gtaja/Projects/altitude/FormulaireQPZ/node_modules/react-native/scripts/codegen/generate-artifacts-executor.js:349:3)

    at /Users/gtaja/Projects/altitude/FormulaireQPZ/node_modules/react-native/scripts/codegen/generate-artifacts-executor.js:374:5

    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

    at generateNativeCodegenFiles (/Users/gtaja/Projects/altitude/FormulaireQPZ/node_modules/react-native/scripts/codegen/generate-artifacts-executor.js:362:13)

    at Object.execute (/Users/gtaja/Projects/altitude/FormulaireQPZ/node_modules/react-native/scripts/codegen/generate-artifacts-executor.js:532:5)

    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gtaja/Projects/altitude/FormulaireQPZ/node_modules/react-native/scripts/generate-codegen-artifacts.js:64:10)

    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14) {

  status: 1,

  signal: null,

  output: [

    null,

    <Buffer >,

    <Buffer 63 70 3a 20 41 6c 74 69 74 75 64 65 2d 69 70 68 6f 6e 65 73 69 6d 75 6c 61 74 6f 72 2f 52 65 61 63 74 2d 43 6f 64 65 67 65 6e 2e 62 75 69 6c 64 2f 44 ... 82 more bytes>

  ],

  pid: 89223,

  stdout: <Buffer >,

  stderr: <Buffer 63 70 3a 20 41 6c 74 69 74 75 64 65 2d 69 70 68 6f 6e 65 73 69 6d 75 6c 61 74 6f 72 2f 52 65 61 63 74 2d 43 6f 64 65 67 65 6e 2e 62 75 69 6c 64 2f 44 ... 82 more bytes>

}





[Codegen] Done.

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code


Build target FormulaireQPZ of project FormulaireQPZ with configuration Debug Altitude
warning: Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'FormulaireQPZ' from project 'FormulaireQPZ')
warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'FormulaireQPZ' from project 'FormulaireQPZ')


Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase.

Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase.



Build failed    01/03/2023 12:12    241.7 seconds
```

Also note that I get the same error if I just rename the default Debug configuration with another name (Debug Altitude) in that case.

I've tried everything, remove DerivedData, clean build folder, reinstall node_modules & pods...

Actually I really have no idea of what happen but I suppose somewhere in React-Codegen or FBReactNativeSpec there is a hardcoded reference to a "Debug" configuration.

I use react-native 0.71.3, with a Mac Intel.

```
yarn react-native info
System:
    OS: macOS 13.2.1
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7267U CPU @ 3.10GHz
    Memory: 36.01 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.19.0 - /var/folders/7_/xtsxclg94s99lhpg5q1f2ypc0000gn/T/yarn--1677669689234-0.446412640910389/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /var/folders/7_/xtsxclg94s99lhpg5q1f2ypc0000gn/T/yarn--1677669689234-0.446412640910389/yarn
    npm: 8.19.3 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.02.20.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /Users/gtaja/.rbenv/shims/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2022.1 AI-221.6008.13.2211.9477386
    Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.15 - /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
    react-native: 0.71.3 => 0.71.3
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Also note that I use the react native new architecture, so I install pods with `RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 pod install`.

This is my Podfile (Flipper disable):

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

project 'FormulaireQPZ', {
  'Debug Altitude' => :debug,
  'Debug Staging' => :debug,
  'Debug Prod' => :debug,
  'Release Altitude' => :release,
  'Release Staging' => :release,
  'Release Prod' => :release
}

target 'FormulaireQPZ' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    # :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'FormulaireQPZTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

I know there is a lot of informations and I ask you a lot but you are my only hope,
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem was that there is spaces in my build configuration name switching from "Debug Altitude" to "DebugAltitude" make it work.
I don't know exactly why but it's look like React-Codegen don't work when the path it build include spaces (and the path include the build configuration name).